# How to display and hide Drupal 7 fields, based on value of a specific field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, cck, drupal-fields

What I am trying to do here is controlling how a group of fields are showing up on node view. I don't want to control them by user role, as this is going to be a node level permission and I don't want these permissions affect other nodes with the same content type.

For example imagine I have three different roles: ROLEA, ROLEB and ROLEC.  Each role has it's own permissions set for accessing to fields. When a node is created for the first time, a user with role of ROLEA, can see couple of fields and can edit the value of those fields. When node is published, a rule/action get called through Rules module, and will set a status field in that node to STAGE1. After this event (a new node created), if user (ROLEA) goes to that node that was just created by herself, those fields that were editable before, should be read-only now. This means when Rules  module, set the value of the status field to STAGE1, when that node wants to get loaded by Drupal, we need to check the status value, and based on that if it was for example STAGE1, modify some other field in that particular node, read only or editable, or in some cases hide them from user. So my guess is to create a module that every time a node of that type, is loading, check the status field (which is a field that we have created in that node type) and based on the value of that field, decide which node should show up or hide. This should override the permission that have been set for those fields on that particular node type.

What I am trying to do is creating a method to control which field is going to be read only /editable / hidden based on the value of a specific field in that content type, which has been set by Roules module, based on different stages of working on that node by different group of users. I am not using Organic Group. I use Drupal 7 and Rules module and couple of other permission related modules. But I found that there is no such a way to handle field visibility in node level,  separate from user roles.

Do you think there is any other way to achieve the same result? I appreciate if you could give me an idea about how to create such a module.

I really appreciate any and all input.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a module and add a hook on node form using : [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)

Using this kind of hook, you can easily modify node form and hide or make read only specific fields, based on whatever you want (user role, field value...)

Comment: Thanks soju,I tried hook_page_alter() for page view and hook_form_alter for page edit.

Answer (score 0):

There are also the [`hook_node_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) hook and [`hook_entity_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_alter/7) hooks that allow you to modify the render array for a node before it is rendered. There you can set field arrays to have `'#access' = FALSE` so they are hidden, or `'#access' = TRUE` to show them.

I'm using this to hide some fields if the date in another field of the node has a time in the past (it's a "subscription expires" field). So I didn't need to change the edit form, just the field display.